# Hadoop Access Control Exception: Permissions

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, elastic-map-reduce

```
Job setup failed : org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=root, access=WRITE, 
inode="/mnt/var/lib/hadoop/tmp/2204827016_Attaching_UU_Codes_5C4141BF22014C8FAD3CD045070589C0/_temporary/1":hadoop:hadoop:drwxr-xr-x

at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:319)

at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:292)
```

It seems that only the user 'hadoop' can write to this location. What are the possible workarounds?

Comment: One possible solution is to start the job as the hadoop user. An other possible solution is to change the folder permissions of your hdfs folders, or add the root user to the hadoop group. [Hadoop HDFS CLI](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your user rights are not enough try sudo or chomnd setting?